# Don't stretch ViewPager background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to set a background image to my ViewPager `(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)`. It can be done via `android:background="@drawable/bg"` - however, it stretches the image.

For `ImageView's` I can set `scaleType="centerCrop"` to prevent this but this doesn't seem to work for `PagerView`. How can I prevent the background from stretching? I've tried adding an `ImageView` as a subview of my `ViewPager` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm.. different image sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there are no 'centerCrop' option for background drawable. How I do it is set your use FrameLayout having the back contain the ImageView using centerCrop, then the front(top) will be your content with transparent background.

Comment: Thanks- this worked. I guess why it was not obvious is because in the GraphicalLayout of my ViewPager layout, it wouldn't allow me to drag in a FrameLayout for some reason. I had to do it manually in xml.